# Meteor loginWithFacebook doesn't work inside WebView

Tags: android, webview, meteor, android-webview

Trying to log in to Meteor using {{loginButtons}} doesn't work inside Android WebView but works great in desktop and mobile browsers.
Does anyone know how i can accomplish this?

Comment: Akshat nailed it, also see https://github.com/awwx/misc/wiki/Meteor-Web-Apps-on-Mobile for general mobile strategies/issues

Answer (score 2):

When logging in with Meteor on facebook it opens up a new window containing a login request from facebook. With a webview this might not be possible & this is likely to be the root issue with why it doesn't work within a WebView.

An option would be to alter the loginbutton to redirect and use the 'touch' style login. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web-no-jssdk/

Note this will take you off your meteor site and to facebook and then redirect back which you might not like. If its ok with you modify the files in the OAuth provider package.

When Meteor receives a callback towards what would come from `Meteor.absoluteUrl('_oauth/facebook?close')` you need to make sure the window doesn't close & instead redirects to your logged in area.

The better solution would be to login with the Android Facebook SDK, then pass off the accessToken back to Meteor to create the facebook account or log in with an existing account.

Comment: Editing the facebook login to only redirect just brings me back to the login button.